# ngx-charts-bar-vertical: what to do when there are too many elements and bars are not drew

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

Using ngx-charts, and particularly the vertical bar chart, I have found that there's a limit of elements over which the bars won't be displayed.

I believe the limit is related to the chart's available width and the number of elements, which of course makes sense.

I replicated the 'issue' modifying the official example (source data is inside data.ts):

- n = limit elements: [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XkTpfs?p=preview) (bars present)[image: bars]
- n+1 elements: [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FdaS9l?p=preview) (bars gone)[image]

My question is: **is there a way to prevent this, like adding a scrollbar when needed, or better?**

**If not, is there an event/log/hook I can use to at least detect it's happening and hide the chart/notify the user?**

It may be interesting to note that when the bars disappear, also their g > path nodes disappear from the DOM.

I'm also pasting here its angular template code because of the 'plunkr must be accompanied by code' restriction, maybe it helps:

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [results]="single"
  [gradient]="gradient"
  [xAxis]="showXAxis"
  [yAxis]="showYAxis"
  [legend]="showLegend"
  [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
  (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: I ended up detecting which was the min width/n ratio to draw a line, and grouping data if the ratio was below that. Felt guilty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `barPadding` input to set the padding between bars (in pixels)
Example:

> [barPadding]="2"

Comment: that will simply reduce that 'n' which is the max num of lines that could be drawn in a fixed width, correct? Won't solve the issue

Comment: No. The reason the bars disappear is they become very thin due to the padding being enforced on them. If you decrease the padding, the bars will be thicker and visible. All of the bars should always be added to the DOM.

Comment: can this value be given in % (percentage)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing values of `barPadding` *(default: 8)* and `groupPadding` *(default: 16)*.

**Ref:** https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/bar-charts/vertical-bar-chart

Comment: Thanks! Now I only need a DeLorean DMC-12 and I'm done :)